# Как сделать видео фон адаптивным?

Tags: html, css

При уменьшении разрешения экрана, сквозь видео фон начинает проступать фоновая картинка (в случае, если видео фон не загрузится) и как вообще сделать так, чтобы видео фон стал адаптивным и подстраивался под размер экрана с сохранением пропорций?

Сам сайт tempes74.beget.tech

Код jsfiddle.net/g1txybej/

```css
.intro {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 400px;
}

.intro_media {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ccc url(../img/video_bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.intro_media:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.intro_media-video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; 
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
    
}
.intro_content {
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section class="relax">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="intro">
                <div class="intro_media">
                    <video class="intro_media-video" src="video/video_bg.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
                </div>
                <div class="intro_content">
                    Relax and trust us!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в iframe не пробовали поместить видео?

Answer (score 1):

Для этого есть такое CSS правило - `object-fit: cover`
Примените его для тега `video` и видео пропорционально растянется на весь размер блока `video`.

Подробнее о [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)